# how to use sphinx with dynamic tables

Tags: sql, database, search, full-text-search, sphinx

Previously we used Sphinx search in our project. It is really fast and quality. What I wonder is, how can I use Sphinx with a constantly modified (row count increasing) table? AFAIK, we need to index the tables with Sphinx in order to use it. So, I cannot search and fidn newly added rows because Sphinx didn't inxdex them yet.

What solution can be used? Should I used different tables as Table1 for searching with Sphinx (indexed) and Table2 for newly added rows and search it with sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Main+Delta indexing.  http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/delta-updates.html

   You have a small index that you regually update, leaving the bulk of the data in main index, that doesnt get updated very often.
2. Real Time Indexes. http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/02/12/rt_performance_basics/

   Sphinx manages indexes internally, so you can add new records on the fly. ie as soon as you insert the data into database, also insert into sphinx.

Comment: Thank you. Which one do you suggest for a very large table (millions of records)? This table is also constantly and concurrently updated by multiple users.

Comment: Its largely down to preference. Personally I use main+delta, but only because I am most familar with it - been using it since before RT indexes where introduced. Know of no reason NOT to use RT indexes.

Comment: Then it's best to test them both and choose according to the performances. Thank you very much